# how to get process handle and id of kernel process in c# code?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, memory

how can I get the process handle and id of kernel process in c# code? when i tried iterating through some of the process i get win32exception "access denied" does these mean these are kernel process?

what i want to do simple look all kernel process in memory and dump it using MiniDumpWriteDump.

Comment: Which processes give the error?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "kernel process".  The System process is just a logical place holder for all the code that runs in ring 0.  There's nothing you can do with the process reference or id, you certainly can't call MiniDumpWriteDump().  AccessDenied will be the only outcome.

Comment: Thanks for response Hans, what is best way to dump all process in kernel mode?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
Process prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("System").FirstOrDefault();
```

You will get PID but you won't be able to get this process handle.

Comment: Maciej, this will again only get the process user mode not in kernel. I later found out only way get this dump is to write the system driver module that will have the access the kernel mode programs and get the dump

Comment: That's right. I would imagine that the only way to access that kind of information would be to run in a kernel mode. Like a driver, as you mentioned. So it's not actually possible from C#.